# How to trigger a macro in Google Sheets when a cell is not blank?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a drop-down menu of values from a database. Each of these values has a numeric code that will populate in a validation cell as long as the value has not been edited. If the value has been edited, the validation cell is blank.

I would like to know when a value has been selected and then edited. To do this, I would like to set up a trigger that copies the code from the validation cell every time it changes to another code - but not when it is made blank. This way, I will have a record of the original value that was selected before it was changed.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
function Untitledmacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   if('O26' !== "") {
    spreadsheet.getRange('P22').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('O26').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
   }
};

function onEdit(e) {
   if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'H26'){
     Untitledmacro()
  }
}
```

And

```
function Untitledmacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   if('O26' !== 0) {
    spreadsheet.getRange('P22').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('O26').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
   }
};

function onEdit(e) {
   if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'H26'){
     Untitledmacro()
  }
}
```

Cell H26 is the drop-down menu

Cell O26 is the validation cell with the numeric code

Cell P22 is where the numeric code is copied to

In both cases above, the macro will run correctly when cell H26 is edited. But it does so whether cell O26 is blank or not.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE

This code is working thanks to [Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Response Builder - Erin" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.range.rowStart == 26 && e.value) {
    e.source.toast("Flag1")
    let v = sh.getRange("O26").getValue();
    if (v !== "") {
      sh.getRange("R26").setValue(sh.getRange("O26").getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

If it is possible, I would like to make this work for a range of data. I would like for it to copy non-blank entries from O26:65 into R26:R65 when H26:H65 is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Enter Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.range.rowStart == 26 && e.value) {
    e.source.toast("Flag1")
    let v = sh.getRange("O26").getValue();
    if (v !== "") {
      sh.getRange("P22").setValue(sh.getRange("O26").getValue());
      sh.getRange("O26").copyTo(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart));
    }
  }
}
```

Final Version Modified by OP:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Response Builder - Erin" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.range.rowStart == 26 && e.value) {
    e.source.toast("Flag1")
    let v = sh.getRange("O26").getValue();
    if (v !== "") {
      sh.getRange("R26").setValue(sh.getRange("O26").getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this combines the two functions together. How would I specify where values are copied to? I had chosen cell P22 for this.

Comment: I had considerable difficulty understanding what you were trying to accomplish.  Presently the script is copying to the range which triggers the script (e.range);

Comment: Ah okay. Apologies for the poor explanation. If I wanted to copy the contents of cell O26 into cell P22, what would I need to modify in this script?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried the script as-is and it did not do anything. I also tried changing `sh.getRange("O26").copyTo(e.range)` to `sh.getRange("P22").copyTo(e.range)` but that did not do anything either.

Comment: Perhaps you don't realize that this script is not meant to be run from the script editor or a  menu. It is meant to be saved in the script editor and you must edit Your Sheet Name replacing it with the sheet you wish the script to run on and when you edit H26 then the script will run if it is the only function with the function definition of onEdit(e). I modified the script to copy the value of O26 into P22

Comment: Thank you for modifying the script and clarifying how to use it. I've updated the script in the script editor and added the correct sheet name to it. However, nothing happens to cell P22 when I edit cell H26 in the specified sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I see you edited the code above. What should I use for "Entry" and "Flag1" in order to test this?

Comment: You don't need to use them at all if you wish.  I use them for debugging purposes.

Comment: Okay thanks. This seems to be on the right track! It copies the value from O26 into P22 whenever O26 is not blank. However, it also copies the formula contents of cell O26 back into cell H26. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I've updated the code and it is working great. Thank you so much for your help! If it is possible, do you know how I could extend to work with a column of data? I would like for it to copy non-blank entries from O26:65 into R26:R65 when H26:H65 is edited.